# Why, at the begining of the tale Jealous Twins, does the storyteller frame the story?

Tags: oral-tradition

The [Verba Africana website](http://www.hum2.leidenuniv.nl/verba-africana/) is a fantastic website that publishes recordings, transcriptions, and analysis of African oral literature.

One of the stories published on the site is called [*Jealous Twins*](http://www.hum2.leidenuniv.nl/verba-africana/ewe/b-jealous-twins-analysis.htm); it is an Ewe tale.

One of the interesting things about the story is that it follows a formula. The storyteller begins by framing the story as something not to be taken seriously:

> ye ŋutinya yia gblɔ ge
>       I am going to tell this story
>   ne ɖeviwo abe fefe fefe ene
>       to children as a play

The storyteller then does a call and response with the audience: she says "Listen to a story" and the audience responds with "Let the story come."

Then, the characters are introduced with "The story moves and lands on a man and the wife," and finally the narrative begins.

Some of the phrases used to frame this story (e.g. "the story moves and lands on [characters]") are used in another Ewe tale recorded on the site: [*Headless Crabs*](http://www.hum2.leidenuniv.nl/verba-africana/ewe/b-headless-crabs-analysis.htm).

Why are these stories framed in this particular way? What effect does this framing have on the story? Why is this framing a convention of Ewe oral literature?